# alignItem: center not working in a flex container containing a material button

Tags: css, flexbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/card-material-ui-cqvet?file=/src/index.js

As you can see in this codesandbox.io, the div inside which there's a button doesn't seem to have an effect on the button inside of it as it behaves like a left float for some reason. Is there something I am missing here. I understand that there are several flex box around that container, but in my understanding it should not have any effect on it, or am I wrong?

```
button: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to align along main axis use

`justify-content: center`

instead of **align-items**